# Инсталятор Wix, который загружает на диск 2 js файла, по выбранному пользователем пути

Tags: install, wix

Инсталятор Wix, который загружает на диск 2 js файла, по выбранному пользователем пути. Не знаю с чего начать(условно File1.js, File2.js)

Comment: [How To: Add a File To Your Installer](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/add_a_file)